# React-Dropzone-Uploader unable to test file upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am building a site in Typescript with REACT.  I am using `react-dropzone-uploader` to handle file uploads in a form.  Uploads work in the broswer just fine.
However, I cannot get [upload() from Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility/#upload) to work.

The code examples from test Library work with their `jsx` and when modified with my helper methods.  However, When I copy the same basic logic to my `react-dropzone-uploader` code it doesn't work. The onChangeEvent never seems to fire.

### Works

```
test('upload file', async () => 
   {
    renderWithProviders(
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="file-uploader">Upload file:
          <input id="file-uploader" type="file" />
        </label>
      </div>
    );

    const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', {type: 'image/png'});
    const input = screen.getByLabelText(startsWith('Upload file'));

    screen.debug(input);
  
    await userEvent.upload(input, file);
  
    expect(input.files[0]).toBe(file);
    expect(input.files.item(0)).toBe(file);
    expect(input.files).toHaveLength(1);
  })
```

#### Doesn't Work

```
 test('FileUpload widget displays successfully', async () => 
  { 
    const uploadDone = jest.fn();
    renderWithProviders(<FileUpload whenUploadComplete={uploadDone} />);

    const dropZone = screen.getByLabelText(startsWith('Drag and Drop a File,'));
    
    expect(dropZone).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug(dropZone);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('dzu-input-id')).toBeInTheDocument();
    
    //resolves a file from project root instead of file.
    const logoFile = loadLocalFile(path.resolve('./src/images/logo.svg'));

    //await userEvent.upload(screen.getByTestId('dzu-input-id'), logoFile);
    await userEvent.upload(dropZone, logoFile);

    expect(uploadDone).toHaveBeenCalled()
   });
```

#### FileUpload Wrapper for `react-dropzone-uploader`

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropzone, 
       { IDropzoneProps, IFileWithMeta, StatusValue } 
       from "react-dropzone-uploader";
import './FileUpload.css'; //copy of React-dropzone-uploader default css
import { theme } from "../shared/theme";
import * as mime from 'mime-types';


export interface fileUploadProps {
  uploadUrl?: string; //allows override for testing
  whenUploadComplete(file: File): void;
}

//TODO: move to test files later
export const devDoNothingUploadUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/post';

export const defaultUploadUrl = devDoNothingUploadUrl;


const FileUpload: React.FC<fileUploadProps> = (props) => 
{
  const { uploadUrl, whenUploadComplete } = props;
  const uploadToUrl = uploadUrl ? uploadUrl : defaultUploadUrl;

  //TODO: MUI Snackbar
  const message = (msg: string) => { console.log(msg); } //{ alert(msg); }

  //TODO: S3 https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3 
  //const getUploadParams = ({meta}:IFileWithMeta) => 
  const getUploadParams: IDropzoneProps['getUploadParams'] = () =>
  { return { url: uploadToUrl } }

  const handleChangeStatus: IDropzoneProps['onChangeStatus'] = 
                            ({ meta, file, remove }, status) =>
  {
    setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
    //console.log(status, meta);
    switch(status)
    {
      case 'ready':
      case 'preparing':
        message(`${meta.name} Preparing for Upload`);
        break;
      case 'started':
      case 'uploading':
      case 'restarted':
        message(`${meta.name} InProgress`);
        break;
      case 'error_file_size':
      case 'error_upload':
      case 'error_upload_params':
      case 'error_validation':
      case 'exception_upload':
      case 'rejected_file_type':
      case 'rejected_max_files':
        message(`${meta.name} ERROR!`);
        //TODO: code to catch and log error
        break;
      case 'done':
        whenUploadComplete(file);
        break;
      case 'headers_received':                
        message(`${meta.name} Upload Complete!`);
        //remove();
    }
    return { meta: { meta } };
  }

  const logStatusChange: IDropzoneProps['onChangeStatus'] = 
                         ({ meta }, status) => 
  { console.log(status, meta, meta.name) }

  const handleSubmit = (files: IFileWithMeta[], allFiles: IFileWithMeta[]) => 
  {
    console.log('files-meta:' + files.map(f => f.meta));
    allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove());
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      maxFiles={1} multiple={false}
      inputContent='Drag and Drop a File, or Click to Browse.'
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      //onChangeStatus={logStatusChange}
      //onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      styles={{ inputLabel: { color: theme.palette.text.secondary }, }}
      submitButtonDisabled={true}
    />
  )
}

export default FileUpload;
```

So How can I test Uploads?
My finish function never gets called, and I can never seem to find updated UI page elements either.  I suspect the `userEvent.upload(dropzone, file);` isn't triggering some event the browser normally does, so how do I trigger the `onChange()` for testing?

---

### UPDATE

#### OnChange Fires, but never gets to `'done' === status`

```
test('DropZone responds to file upload event', async () => 
   { 
      const getUploadParams: IDropzoneProps['getUploadParams'] = () =>
      { return { url: 'https://httpbin.org/post' } }  

      const handleChangeStatus = jest.fn();

      renderWithProviders(<Dropzone maxFiles={1} multiple={false}
                                    inputContent='Send a file.'
                                    getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
                                    onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
                          />);
 
      //const dropZone = screen.getByLabelText(startsWith('Drag and Drop a File,'));
      const dropZone = screen.getByLabelText(startsWith('Send a file'));
     
      expect(dropZone).toBeInTheDocument();
      screen.debug(dropZone);
 
      //expect(screen.getByTestId('dzu-input-id')).toBeInTheDocument();
     
      //resolves from project root instead of file.
      const logoFile = loadLocalFile(path.resolve('./src/images/logo.svg'));
 
      //await userEvent.upload(screen.getByTestId('dzu-input-id'), logoFile);
      //await userEvent.upload(dropZone, logoFile);
      //await fireEvent.change(dropZone, { target: { file: [logoFile] } });
      await fireEvent.drop(dropZone, { dataTransfer: { files: [logoFile] } });
 
      expect(handleChangeStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
```

The key is `await fireEvent.drop(dropZone, { dataTransfer: { files: [logoFile] } });` triggers the onChange event.
The Problem is in the Test enviornment, `XMLHttpRequest#onReadyStateChange()`  never fires with the proper parameters to trigger the [callback handler in `react-dropzone-uploader`](https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader/blob/89aa88acf753962398fee967d0e4b5ac5d53065a/src/Dropzone.tsx#L545).

How do I trigger that callback properly in a JEST test?